# Unity Camera Clamping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make my Unity Camera for a first person game to be clamped between around -70ish maximum, 85 minimum, however whenever I clamp my camera between these spots, it will not rotate. I tried messing around with some different values, however that did not seem to fix anything or just made my camera jitter around. I am still learning C#, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float CameraSpeed = 5;
    public Vector3 CamMovement;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CamMovement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0, 0);
        CamMovement.y = Mathf.Clamp(CamMovement.y, -88, 88);

        transform.Rotate(-CamMovement.y * CameraSpeed, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

rotates from the current rotation about the given degrees.

=> You are thereby only clamping the amount of rotation that can happen within one frame, not the overall resulting rotation!

You should rather store the rotated amount and do e.g.

```
private float rotationX;

void Update()
{
    var input = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    rotationX += input * CameraSpeed;
    rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX , -88, 88);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-rotationX, 0, 0);
}
```

or if you need this relative to an arbitrary initial rotation

```
private float rotationX;
private Quaternion initialRotation;

private void Start()
{
    initialRotation = transform.localRotation;
}

private void Update()
{
    var input = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    rotationX += input * CameraSpeed;
    rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX , -88, 88);

    transform.localRotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.Euler(-rotationX, 0, 0);
}
```